# What content do the charts from the Lydian Chromatic Concept of Tonal Organization contain?

Tags: theory, lydian-chromatic-concept

I recently purchased George Russell's seminal work, the *Lydian Chromatic Concept of Tonal Organization*, however my used copy is missing its fold-out charts. The text refers these charts extensively. What information is presented there? Or alternatively, where may I acquire a copy of them to complete my volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [http://monoskop.org/File:Russell_George_Lydian_Chromatic_Concept_of_Tonal_Organization_4th_ed.pdf](http://monoskop.org/File%3aRussell_George_Lydian_Chromatic_Concept_of_Tonal_Organization_4th_ed.pdf)

I can't download it at work, but it probably has what you're looking for.  If it does, let me know and I'll tell you how I found it.

Comment: From what I can tell it has one chart, Chart A.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it includes the chart. My copy is from a 1950's typewriter manuscript. The typesetting for this version is far superior. THANK YOU. (And yes, I would like to learn how you discovered it too.)

Comment: I googled "Lydian Chromatic concept of tonal" and it was the first thing I saw.  :)

Comment: When I researched this some time ago, I only found the site selling this latest printing. I wound up buying an old, albeit incomplete, printing from an online auction. This will aid my study...

Comment: When you're googling your way through the internet to find things like this, it's a good idea to look for "pdf" files. When I put in those words, one of the results in the little dropdown menu was "lydian chromatic concept of tonal organization pdf". I picked that one. You will often be able to find entire books and the like in links to pdf files. So, if you see a link to a pdf file, it's a good idea to have a look at it.